# Prove that a sequence does not converge to a number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a sequence $\langle a_n \rangle_{n = 1}^\infty$ in which $a_n = \cfrac{n - \sum_{i = 0}^k 3^i}{3^{k + 1}}$, where $k \ge 0$ is a unique integer such that $\sum_{i = 0}^k 3^i \le n < \sum_{i = 0}^{k + 1} 3^i$. I am trying to prove that this sequence does not converge to $\frac{1}{2}$, and then see if I could find a subsequence of $\langle a_n \rangle_{n = 1}^\infty$ that converges to $\frac{1}{2}$. To show the former, so far, I've tried the proof of contradiction, that is, to suppose that $\langle a_n \rangle_{n = 1}^\infty$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$. Then, I used the fact that $\sum_{i = 0}^k 3^i = \cfrac{1 - 3^{k + 1}}{1 - 3} = -\cfrac{1 - 3^{k + 1}}{2}$, to calculate
$$\begin{align*}
\left| a_n - \frac{1}{2} \right| &= \left| \cfrac{n - \sum_{i = 0}^k 3^i}{3^{k + 1}} - \frac{1}{2} \right| \\
&= \left| \cfrac{2n + 1 - 3^{k + 1} - 3^{k + 1}}{2 \cdot3^{k + 1}} \right| \\
&= \left| \cfrac{2(n - 3^{k + 1}) + 1}{2 \cdot3^{k + 1}} \right|.
\end{align*}$$

I am trying to see if I could choose $\epsilon$ somehow, so there is no positive $N$ that guarantees $\left| a_n - \frac{1}{2} \right|$ for all integers $n \ge N$, but I guess I am stuck (not even sure that I am in the right direction). At the same, I can hardly come up with a subsequence of $\langle a_n \rangle_{n = 1}^\infty$ that converges to $\frac{1}{2}$. I notice the $3$, so I don't know if it has anything to deal with calculation in base $3$. Could you please help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: As you’ve defined it, $$a_n=\frac1{3^{k+1}}\left(n-\frac{3^{k+1}-1}2\right)=\frac{2n+1}{3^{k+1}}-\frac12\,.$$ This sequence does not have any convergent subsequence: it is an increasing arithmetic sequence with constant difference $\frac2{3^{k+1}}$.

Comment: Working in base $3$ what's the range of $n$ in terms of digits and lowest/highest number? After that what is $\sum_{i=0}^k 3^k$ in base $3$?And what is $1/2$ in base $3$? Also what happens in base $3$ when you divide by $3^{k+1}$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you, but I thought an increasing sequence can still be convergent if it is bounded above. A subsequence of an increasing sequence is increasing, and thus it may be convergent. Could you please clarify a bit?

Comment: @little_sky: A strictly increasing arithmetic sequence cannot be bounded above. If $a_{n+1}=a_n+d$ for each $n$, where $d$ is a positive constant, then $a_n=a_0+nd$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and that can be made as large as you like by taking $n$ large enough.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh I see! That makes perfect sense now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @little_sky: You’re very welcome.